# QString indent the mutiline line string with the first line

Tags: c++, qt

I have multi line QString for example

```
QString str1;
str1="match \n" "case \n" "end match;";
```

When the string is inserted i want the new lines to be inserted with the indentation of the first line. For example the output should be

```
   match
   case
   end match;
```

But when i insert the string now i am actually getting this output, the first line is indented correctly and the next two line are not indented

```
        match
  case
  end match;
```

How to do this, any suggestions

The current try i am doing is like below

```
QTextCursor cursor = textCursor();
 const QTextBlock previousBlock = cursor.block().previous();
QString indentText = previousBlock.text();
cursor.beginEditBlock();
cursor.insertText(indentText.left(tabSettings.firstNonSpace(indentText)));
cursor.endEditBlock();
setTextCursor(cursor);
```

what i am trying to do is, i catch the previous block of code and when the user press enter the cursor is set to that position and when i enter a single line string it is inserted correctly according to the indentation, for the multiline string somehow when newlines are inserted i have to force the second and the rest of lines to follow the first line indentation behaviour

Comment: show the code please

Comment: Are you searching for QString build-in mechanism or have your own algorithm? Do you have any code?  The code you shown does not do any indentation.

Comment: I am mostly looking for QString build in mechanism if possible, i am not having any code at the moment

Comment: We are not here to teach you how to program or write solution for you. I can only say that `QString` doesn't currently have indentation mechanism - you have to write own or use different component.

Comment: i have submitted what i have tried so far, i catch the previous block indentation space and when i enter a single line string it is done correclty now when new lines are added the strings are not indented correctly, my thinking is should i split the string based on new lines and then find the first line indent position and force the remaining lines to follow the first